# Validade a form field only when it is visible

Tags: javascript

I'm using a script that if you choose "representante" it shows 2 additional fields. The problem is, they are required. This is a problem when they're not visible and yet it is needed to submit the form.

How can I make those additional fields required **only if they're visible**? I've been searching for a solution but I can't seem to make anything work since I'm not a developer. I was doing good til the testing started

```js
$("#dropdown_menu").change(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var CuurentSelect = $(this).val();
  var option = $("#dropdown_menu option:nth-child(3)").val();
  if (CuurentSelect == "Representante") {
    console.log("Representante selected");
    $('#container_nome_da_loja').attr('style', 'display: block !important');
    $('#container_link_do_site').attr('style', 'display: block !important');
  } else {
    $('#container_nome_da_loja').attr('style', 'display: none !important');
    $('#container_link_do_site').attr('style', 'display: none !important');

  }
});
```

Comment: Please visit [help], take [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, ***[search for related topics on SO](https://www.google.com/search?q=required+when+visible+site:stackoverflow.com)***; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output, preferably in a [Stacksnippet](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/)

Comment: Also `$('#container_nome_da_loja').toggle(CuurentSelect === "Representante")`